# web2py delete query

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py

Hi have the following table

```
db.define_table('templates',
    Field('id','id'),
    Field('user_id',db.auth_user),
    Field('name','string'))

db.define_table('user_settings',
    Field('id','id'),
    Field('user_id',db.auth_user),
    Field('default_template', db.templates)
    Field('name','string'))
```

The Form:

```
def templates():
    form = SQLFORM.grid(db.templates, 
    links [lambda row: A(SPAN(_class='icon trash icon-trash'), SPAN(T('Delete'),_class='buttontext button'), _class='button btn', _href=URL('delete',args=[db.templates,row.id]))])]
    return dict(form=form)
```

my delete function is

```
def delete():
    if request.args(0) == 'templates': 
        db(db.templates.user_id == auth.user_id).delete()
        return dict(form=redirect(URL('templates')))
    return dict(form=redirect(URL('index')))
```

when i delete a record from `templates`
the associated record of it in `db.user_settings` is also get removed

with a custom form generated with simple `SQLFORM(query, record, deletable=True)` which create a check butoon "delete" it works fine and `db.user_settings.default_template` will only be set to None.

how to prevent this ?
Is my delete query false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it with this

```
def delete():
    if request.args(0) == 'templates':
        if db.templates[request.args(1)].id == auth.user_id:
            db(db.templates.id ==  request.args(1)).delete()
            return dict(form=redirect(URL('templates')))
    return dict(form=redirect(URL('index')))
```